# set an environment variable using bash_profile, but echo does not return

Tags: bash, environment-variables

recently on mac, i set an environment variable so that it is present in a new shell. today opening a shell it no longer appears in a new shell even when i set it. i have been using:

```
export "AVARIABLE=example" >>~/.bash_profile
```

which has worked fine until now when i run:

```
echo $AVARIABLE
```

i just get a blank line as if it doesn't exist.

this is happening any time i try to set an environment variable permanently now. i can't see what i'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a `.profile` in addition to your `.bash_profile`? If so, the latter is ignored

Comment: sorry to be slow, but how would this fit into my current piece of code? my confusion comes from that before this code worked fine and i can't understand why there has been a change.

Answer (score 11):

You are missing an `echo` in your command. Try this and and then source the `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo export "AVARIABLE=example" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

You also have to source the `.profile` after you make changes to it.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: hi, i just tried this and still cannot run it in a new shell. i ran `printenv` and i can see it is plainly there but it still doesn't return a value.

Comment: @WJE - hi, you are missing `echo`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: thank you, this does work. is there a reason that you know of why my code would have worked previously and now doesn't? i can't see why that would have changed.

Comment: `echo` is required for appending the `export` to the `.bash_profile`.